# Write text upon equivalent

Tags: equations, sequence

I want to get below the image. But when I write this $F \equiv^{SAT} G$, not getting the intended result.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [José Carlos Santos](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/134805/jos%c3%a9-carlos-santos)
has already pointed out in the comments, `\stackrel` will do the trick. Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
    F\stackrel{\text{\scriptsize SAT}}{\equiv}G
\]
\end{document}
```

Note `\mathclap` is not used here because SAT is too wide to discard its width (inevitably ugly otherwise).

Comment: I'd prefer `\overset{\text{SAT}}{\equiv}`

Comment: But how to measure the text size? Give one example.

Comment: @S.M. I use something like this in my paper: `\stackrel{\mathclap{\scriptstyle(a)}}{=}` in an `aligned` environment, so that `=` will be aligned perfectly. Here (a) is quite short (narrow).